# Каковы преимущества Kotlin перед Java для разработки под Android для программиста?

Tags: android, kotlin

Каковы преимущества Kotlin перед Java для разработки под Android для программиста?

Я поверхностно знаком с Java, прочитал только краткое описание Kotlin, вижу пока что только:
- более компактный синтаксис
- есть свойства
- вроде бы есть ссылки на функции (что теоретически могло бы сильно упростить задание всяких обработчиков нажатий на кнопки и т. п.)
- можно объявлять функции без классов

Еще где то видел, что у Kotlin есть nullable и не-nullable переменные, только непонятно, что это дает и почему это так важно.

Задаю вопрос в связи с тем, что решаю - на каком языке начать новый проект под Android - не очень большое приложение для терминала сбора данных.

Comment: ну и бонусом coroutines

Comment: Ну и еще есть немного неплохо сахара

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выбирайте Котлин. С ним гораздо лучше. После него Ява будет казаться многословной и опасной.

Преимущества с ходу могу такие назвать:

1. `data` классы с дефолтными значениями аргументов. Больше не нужны громадные классы-модели. Просто описываете конструктор и всё - toString, getter/setter, equals/hashCode будут сгенерированы автоматически и невидимо.
2. Операции с коллекциями. Для преобрахования листа одного типа в другой не нужно писать цикл. Он будет написан за вас в байт-коде. `val intList = stringList.map { it.toInt() }`
3. Функции-расширения. Крайне удобны. Заменяют `Utilities` классы со статическими методами и выглядят крайне приятно: `listOfObjectWithStringAndInt.sortBy { it.intValue }`
4. Для конкретно андроида можно использовать `kotlin-android-extensions` - в классы работающие с разметкой делаете импорт и вам будут доступны сгенерированные переменные для всех вьюх в разметке.
5. `Nullability` - безумно удобная штука. Если вам надо вызвать метод на переменной, которая может быть `null`, то просто пишете `nullableVar?.methodName()` - метод вызовется только если переменная не `null`. Если вы объявите переменную как `не-nullable` - компилятор не позволит вам передать туда `nullable` переменную. Это решает множество проблем.

Comment: Все перечисленное имеет свою цену. И если для простых приложений "и так сойдет", то для более сложных вещей надо хотя бы примерно представлять, а что именно будет скомпилировано в сравнении с той же джавой. Я сам очень люблю Kotlin, но меня порой посещают мысли, что не породит ли он волну "не думающих о последствиях" разработчиков. :)

Comment: @rjhdby, не спорю) Сам сталкивался с ситуациями, где только понимание во что превращаются фигурные скобки при трансляции в Яву помогали понять почему код не работает) Так что да, знание Явы нужно)

Answer (score 6):

Это лично мое, оценочное, мнение. Оно не претендует на истину в последней инстанции и другие люди совершенно законно могут иметь противоположное мнение.

> более компактный синтаксис

Не "компактный", а идеоматический.
Процесс разработки бОльшей частью подразумевает не написание кода, а чтение уже написанного. Чем проще код читается - тем более продуктивен процесс разработки.

Если в совсем грубом приближении, то Kotlin можно описать как Java с огромным количеством синтаксического сахара, который позволяет реализовать то же самое написав сильно меньше, но байткод будет тем же.

> есть свойства
>
> вроде бы есть ссылки на функции
>
> можно объявлять функции без классов

См. пункт 1.

> Еще где то видел, что у Kotlin есть nullable и не-nullable переменные, только непонятно, что это дает и почему это так важно.

Nullability - это попытка сделать систему типов более строгой. Тут прямая зависимость: чем строже система типов - тем меньше ошибок пройдет дальше компиляции. NPE - это "ошибка на миллиард долларов"(с) - боль и ненависть языков, где она есть. Любое ужесточение, позволяющее ее избежать - благо.

> Задаю вопрос в связи с тем, что решаю - на каком языке начать новый проект под Android - не очень большое приложение для терминала сбора данных.

Тут все зависит от того, кем вы себя видите в будущем. Если только Android разработчиком, то Kotlin ваш выбор. Если в принципе разработчиков под JVM (в кровавом энтерпрайзе например), то Java. Но если по крупному, то Java - must have в любом случае, хотя бы потому, что не зная ее вы не будете понимать, что происходит в Kotlin.

Comment: Но на Котлине можно писать и на бэк. Есть несколько компаний(вроде, Тинькофф) которые так делают. Также есть доклады на эту тему.